# Is it possible to start a command from bash and send a keystroke to it

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to start Firefox from bash and I want it to open the webconsole on start (this can be done by pressing F12 rigth after it started). Is there a bash command that starts the programm and sends the F12 key while starting? I already looked at xdotool and tried to create a bash script, that starts firefox and then sends the key with xdotool, but the xdotool command isn't run until I close firefox.

Comment: Hmm, you could background firefox with `firefox &` and then kluge in a `sleep 7` or something to wait for firefox to spin up. A better solution might be to configure firefox to show the webconsole by default, but that might require an add-on or delving through `about:config` ?

Comment: I already searched for methods that start the webconsole, but the only option I found is the -jsconsole option and that starts the browserconsole instead of the webconsole. I haven't found any config options or addons that do this, thats why I'm searching for a way to do it in a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh 
set -e #abort if anything fails
firefox & #run firefox in the background
pid=$!    #remember its pid

#Poll X until firefox sets up a window
#remember the X id of the window
while [ -z "$id" ]; do
    id=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid $pid) 
    sleep 0.1 #poll interval
done

#Bring the window to the front and send it the F12 key
xdotool windowactivate $id && xdotool key F12
disown "$pid"
```

This isn't very robust, though. Configuring `firefox` to open the console by itself would be better.

Comment: Is there an urgent call from the NYSE for some risky business? If not then `sleep 1` is fully sufficient.